# Write Jackson Custom Deserializer for a particular attribute in an hierarchical JSON map

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

JSON Object:

```
["emp" : {
        "departments": [
            "modules": [
                {
                    "tasks": [
                        {
                            "resources": 100,
                            "notes": "" 
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        ]
    }]
```

I would want to map the above JSON onto a `List<Emp>`object. My object mapper would look like:
`List<Emp> emps = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(jsonString, Emp[].class));`

This simple object mapper works well.
My problem is I have to deserialize `tasks` object from the JSON on to the `Task` object in a different manner.

I understand that we can write a custom deserializer using jackson, but that is not solving my case.
I have written a `CustomeDeserializer` for the `Task` object, but registering this to the Object Mapper as follows would try to serialize the whole JSON (`List<Emp>`) as a a task object.

```
SimpleModule mod = new SimpleModule("MyModule");
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

      mod.addDeserializer(Task.class,
          new CustomDeserializer(Task.class));
      mapper.registerModule(mod);
```

Is there a way to specify the `CustomDeserializer` only for a particular attribute during parsing?
Or is there an alternative for this ?

Note: I cannot change my DTO's to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives for parsing JSON with Jackson. You can use Jacksons `Tree model` parsing or the `streaming API`. Both require more code than just `mapper.readValue(jsonString, Emp[].class)` but it's a lot better than implementing your own JSON parsing. You can read about them in the Jackson documentation [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)